# "make it clear that" or "make clear that"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I've only learn the former one "make it clear that" but "make clear that" is seen everywhere. Do they mean the same? Are they both grammatical and acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20it%20clear%20that%2C%20make%20clear%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20it%20clear%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20clear%20that%3B%2Cc0) which shows that both forms are common: overall, **make it clear that** is more common. **make clear that** seems to be gaining ground, but this could be due to changes in the types of usage.

Here is an approximate guide to how the two terms are used.

1) When a person or organization is providing information, this form is used:

> At the outset let me **make it clear that** I describe research - [Evaluating mobility aids for the blind](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=eCgrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA101&dq=%22make%20it%20clear%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-5-3Fn6zOAhWEWhoKHQKXDJQQ6AEIPjAG#v=onepage&q=%22make%20it%20clear%20that%22&f=false)

2) When referring to a document,  this form is more common.

> Thirteenth- and fourteenth-century records, moreover, **make clear that** the piers were of stone at that time - [Traffic and politics](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=xgo3fmb1qY0C&pg=PA21&dq=%22make%20clear%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9udvCnazOAhXEWRoKHcYqA8cQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=%22make%20clear%20that%22&f=false)